# Adding a title caption with some specific style

Tags: tables

I am a newbie to Latex, this is an example of creating a table from the wiki latex tutorial https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cline{1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I am wondering how to add a title for this table with the same style in this example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special caption format can be achieved with the `caption` package and its `\captionsetup` command.

Use `labelsep=newline` option to separate the `Table 1` label from the real caption text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,labelsep=newline}
\captionof{table}{This is some data} % Or just `\caption{This is some data} if the tabular environment is in a floating environment.. 
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cline{1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

A second 'caption' below the table: Use `\captionof*{...}{...}` etc. to prevent the numbering and entry to the List of Tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{%
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline}
\captionof{table}{This is some data}
}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cline{1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof*{table}{This is another caption}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
foo & foo \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Dummy table -- just for checking}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, your answer does what I asked for. But, how to make this caption style works on the title only? because I have another caption below the table and I don't need it to be changed.

Comment: @ahmedabobakr: That wasn't in your question. Why do you need a second caption at all?

Comment: I need to add some details about the data below the table. I know that your answer is perfect and completely targets the question, so I chose it. I appreciate if you know a way to disable this setup with the other caption

Comment: @ahmedabobakr: The second caption must be unnumbered then, of course?

Comment: If you mean by unnumbered is without ( Table 1 ) in the beginning then yes.

Comment: Thank you Christian, I have found what I was looking for, using {tablenotes}

Comment: @ahmedabobakr: see the update please ...